# Remove leading zeros from column (non function)

Tags: excel, vba

This is posted by Dammer15 and this is what I'm looking for. However I need it to loop through the entire column. I would ask there directly but I can not comment yet.

```
Dim My_Number As String
Dim i As Integer
My_Number = Range("AJ")
For i = 1 To Len(My_Number) - 1
If InStr(1, My_Number, "0") = 1 Then
    My_Number = Right(My_Number, Len(My_Number) - 1)
 Else
    Range("AJ") = My_Number
    Exit For
 End If
Next
```

Comment: you can not do this `My_Number = Range("AJ")`  You will need to loop through the range and look at each cell individually.  But are they all numbers or do they have text in the string?

Comment: It's alphanumeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to match the lead 0s instead of the bulky replace function you currently have:

```
Sub TestRe()
    Dim LastCell As Range: Set LastCell = ActiveSheet.Columns("AJ").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("AJ1", LastCell)
    Dim Cell As Range: For Each Cell In Rng
        Cell.Value = RemoveLead0s(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
End Sub

Function RemoveLead0s(AlphaNum As String) As String
    RemoveLead0s = AlphaNum

    ' RegExp requires "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" reference
    Dim RegEx As New RegExp
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "^0*"
        If .test(AlphaNum) Then RemoveLead0s = .Replace(AlphaNum, "")
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to iterate through each value.  I would recommend uploading the whole range into an array and then looping through that instead:

```
Sub foo()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AJ").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("AJ1", .Cells(lastRow, "AJ"))
    arr = rng.Value
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        My_Number = arr(i, 1)
        For j = 1 To Len(arr(i, 1)) - 1
        If Mid(arr(i, 1), j, 1) <> 0 Then
            arr(i, 1) = Right(arr(i, 1), Len(arr(i, 1)) - (j - 1))
            Exit For
         End If
        Next j
    Next i
    rng.Value = arr
End With

End Sub
```